# How to prototype a smart tv app

Tags: android, iphone, samsung-mobile

For simple presentation purposes, I am looking for a way to easily show how content on a television screen moves as I navigate on a paired in-synce mobile device.  For example, as I perform some function on my mobile device, I would like to show a corresponding screen of output or result.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to connect your cell phone to your TV. It needs to be connected with WiFi (Smart TV) or with cable (HDMI). Then you'll see your phone on TV, and basically use PowerPoint for android or any other presentation reader.